# Sequential compactness of an interval

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Show that $[0,1]\setminus \{1/2\} $ is not sequentially compact.
My attempt at a solution: I need to find a sequence that has limit $1/2$.

How about $x_{n}=\dfrac{n+1}{2n+3}$?

Comment: To show that $A=[0,1] \setminus \{1/2\}$ is not sequentially compact, you must find a sequence in $A$ that does not converge in $A$. It seems that you have found such a sequence!

Answer (score 1):

While that surely works, perhaps $x_n := \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}$ would be even easier.